# How is it possible that in /home `ls` returns `valo` but `cd /valo` returns `No such file or directory`?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, directory

How is it possible that the folder is there yet isn't at the same time?

```
valo@Castor:~$ cd /home
valo@Castor:/home$ cd /valo
bash: cd: /valo: No such file or directory
valo@Castor:/home$ ls
valo
valo@Castor:/home$ cd /valo
bash: cd: /valo: No such file or directory
valo@Castor:/home$
```

[image: image of terminal]

Comment: Try `cd /home/valo`

Comment: I did, the result is the same.

Comment: `/home` is `/` then `home`. You could try `cd /`, `cd home`, `cd valo` to get the same effect. `cd ~` also can achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Schrödinger's folder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What the comments have suggested, but not said, is that the `/` character typed before the name `valo` makes the system look for the directory `valo` as a subdirectory of `/` or the root of the file system.

The thing about the `cd` command to remember is that it will either look for a "relative" path or an "absolute" path based on the path entered. When the path entered begins with a `/` it looks for an absolute path, meaning it starts from the root of the file system. When the character is anything else, it looks for the path to begin in the current location.

In your example, when you are in `/home` and type `cd /valo` it looks for an absolute path of `/` (filesystem root) `valo`, which does not exist. If you type `cd valo` it looks for `valo` in the current directory. If that is in the `/home` directory, it will find it.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic commands that you can use to navigate directories on the terminal:

`cd` and `cd ~` will both take you to the same place - your users's home directory

`pwd` will print the current directory and this is also listed at the command line prompt.

If you are in the directory `/home` and you type `ls` and see

```
valo@Castor:/home$ ls 
valo
```

Then you know `valo` is a subdirectory of the current directory.  To change to that directory, type the command:

```
cd valo
```

Some equivalent commands are `cd ./valo` and `cd /home/valo`

Sometimes these other ways of specifying the subdirectory are needed.